# React - How to trigger animation if value of div/span is updated?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following problem: I'm working on a react app and I have a div, which contains multiple span-tags. The value of these span tags are dynamically changed and whenever a change of these values occured, I'd like to trigger an animation. While the values are changing without any problems, the animation only triggers during the first initial load. Afterward it fails to trigger. Is there any way I can tell or force my app to trigger the animation when the value of the div-container is changed?

Here is a shortened example of my code:

```
<div className="animation">
  <span>{value}</span>
  <span>{value2}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: you can use this.setState to update dynamic value and it automatically re-render.

Comment: Please post your whole component code for better answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how your values are structured but here's my recommendation

Make an animated span component and get the value as a prop.

Then whenever that value changes, The span component will re-render and you will see the animation.

Answer (score 0):

Put your `value` and `value2`  in to the state, and then change the state value and your component will re-render.

Like this:

```
   constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
        value: 'animation',
        value2: 'animation'
        };
    }

changeAnimation() {
    this.setState({
     value: 'animation2',
     value2: 'animation2'
    })
}
```